# How to create a failover page for an Elastic Beanstalk auto-scaling environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create a failover or maintenance page for my web application.

I want the page to be displayed under the following circumstances:

- When I update my elastic beanstalk application
- 500, 501, 502, 503, and 504 status code
- In the event that AWS goes down
- If I want to perform maintenance on the site

I have read through AWS's documentation and none of it works for my instance. All help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do if you are using Route 53. For another DNS provider consult their documentation for DNS Failover.

1) Create an S3 website with a bucket name that is exactly the same as your domain name such as www.example.com

2) Setup a landing page (index.html) that says something like "site under maintenance back up soon".

3) In Route 53, change your primary Record Set entry for www.example.com to be Failover and Primary and set Evaluate Target Health: Yes.

4) In Route 53, create a new Record Set entry for www.example.com to be Failover and Secondary with an ALIAS to the S3 website.

A Google search on "AWS Route 53 DNS Failover" will pull up lots of reference material.

Comment: I have tried these steps multiple times and it does not work. I will try again using the steps provided and let you know my result, thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you are testing from a different machine that has not been to your website. Often you will see long delays on the same machine detecting the DNS change. Also shorten any TTLs for your domains (does not apply to ALIAS records).

Comment: Did you create a "Target Health" check and assign it to your Route 53 Resource Record? How long does it take for the health check to fail? You will need to wait that long for DNS failover.

Comment: After step 3 my webapp works fine, however after step 4 my webapp is just always being redirected to the s3 bucket.

Comment: Post your Route 53 Resource Records for both failover records and the health check.

Comment: I could not add s3 bucket secondary failover recordset. It says 
"The record set could not be saved because:
- Alias Target contains an invalid value."

Comment: What did you enter as the Alias value? Route 53: Amazon S3 bucket – The name of the record must match the name of your Amazon S3 bucket. For example, if the name of your bucket is acme.example.com, the name of this record must also be acme.example.com. You must configure the bucket for website hosting.